# If offered a full time job, am I able to leave my apprenticeship?

Tags: communication, job-change, internship, united-kingdom, quitting

I've been at company X for almost a year and a half now doing an IT apprenticeship. I'm not a particular fan of how I am taught at my college and I have already achieved my level 2 in the first year as I have a new lecturer for the second year.

I enjoy working here and everyone is very friendly and helpful, but I'm not very into the industry we specialize in - my knowledge of this business hasn't improved over the time being here.

Company Y has sent me an email asking for contact details and a CV, which may lead to a full time job in an industry I will enjoy and is something I know better.

If I am offered the job, am I able to leave the apprenticeship early?

Comment: "Company Y has sent an email to myself asking for contact details and a  CV which may lead to a full time job" - Your title says you got a job offer, but this sounds like only the first step (it may or may not become an offer).

Comment: it doesn't sound like a solid enough commitment to get your hopes up with.

Comment: @Brandin Any ideas what I could change it to?

Comment: @Barry It sounds like they're recruiting. If you're interested, follow-up, apply, go to the interview if they invite you, etc. In the meantime, check your contract/agreement with the apprenticeship to see how much notice you need to give.

Comment: It sounds like you're still a student, is that correct? If so, is the apprenticeship part-time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific to one individual and company. The answer is in the terms of your apprenticeship, which we do not have access to, and would not be broadly applicable to a general situation.

Answer (score 1):

On the information given I don't think it's a firm enough offer to read too much into. But in answer to your question, yes, you can leave an apprenticeship early.
Details may vary in different locales, but unless you're in a draconian third world country where apprentice= virtual slave, you can leave whenever you want, just give notice like any other job. Check your contract to see what obligations you have to comply with.

Comment: Thank you. I do agree it's not firm enough to look into - but just clarifying I am able to leave my apprenticeship if wanted.

Comment: definitely, it happens a lot

Comment: I'd just like to add that it may be in the contract that you must pay back the training costs  if you dont serve X years - it was in mine on an apprenticeship but when people left they never exercised this "right" - and whether that would stand up I'm not sure.

Comment: That depends in the UK an old school apprenticeship was a binding multi year contract - though nowadays often  it just means trainee /cheap labour.

Check your contract is the answer